# From $xz+yz+xy$ to $\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Self learning linear algebra I came to a proof for inner product. Problem doesn't matter, the thing is that within the proof the author makes an step that I honestly don't understand:

\begin{align}
\vdots\,\,\, \\
& xz+yz+xy \\[10pt]
= {} & \\[10pt]
& \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)^2 - \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
\end{align}

.... and then the proof continues. Since I want to really learn I can't simply assume it's true, I want to know what am I missing. I get out of high school some time ago and  maybe it's obvious for anyone but me, but if you can help me it'll be nice.

Comment: Multiply $x+y+z$ by $x+y+z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall

$$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy$$
and 
$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)$$
hence note that in the both above cases the result is the sum of the square of every term plus twice the product of terms taken two by two, hence we generalize this result
$$(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2+2\sum_{i< j}x_i x_j$$

Comment: Careful, it is $(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2 - x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 = \sum_{i \ne j} x_i x_ j = 2 \sum_{i < j} x_ i x_ j$

Comment: @vonbrand you're absolutely right. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

$$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2 x z + 2 y z + 2 x y. $$
As you are out of practice, you should carefully confirm this yourself.